# How do I run wire for LED panels with a 0v-10v dimmer?

Tags: electrical, led, dimmer-switch

I have two [LED ceiling lights with 0-10V dimming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J9MWTW7) and want to wire them to two individual [dimmer switches](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K2CH5VH) (I want to be able to dim them independently of each other). I'm trying to figure out how to wire them. Can I use 14/2 wire to feed the hot/neutral/ground wires from the switch to the lights, then use 18/2 thermostat wire for the purple and gray low voltage wires?

I have seen other people mention the Romex Simpull NM-B-PCS Duo Cable, but I only need less than 50ft of wire and I've only seen it being sold in lengths greater than 100ft.

Comment: That combination of wiring should be fine. Make sure any wire going inside walls is rated for that use; you don't want insulation that might help feed a fire if one starts.

Comment: Do the instructions for your light fixtures say they support NEC Class 2 wiring for the dimming control wires?

Comment: These are specifically listed as Commercial Lighting, and 0-10v dimming is, AIUI, used primarily in commercial settings. Is this a commercial installation or home installation?

Comment: @keshlam Is something like this rated for walls? https://www.lowes.com/pd/50-ft-18-2-Thermostat-Wire-By-the-Roll/3128547

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel one part of the product spec sheet says LED Driver Class: P. class 2 (I hope that’s what you’re referring to)

Comment: @FreeMan this is a home installation

Comment: Here is a photo of the spec sheet that came with the light: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ip5940xqcac1f5p/led%20panel%20spec%20sheet.jpg?dl=0